# Can I set the session variable in the html template? - Meteor

Tags: session, meteor

Usually I can access the session and get its value in the html by registering global session as follows:

```
Template.registerHelper('session',function(input){ 
return Session.get(input); 
});
```

And then using it inside the html as follow:

```
{{session "itemId"}}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to set a session value inside html?

Why I want to do this?
Because I want to create chat app and every conversation needs to have unique channel name. I want to change the channel name session when the user clicks on the user he wants to chat with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is an *event handler*:

> when the user clicks

Describes an event.

Your html, templates, and template *helpers* should concern themselves with *presentation*. As helpers run reactively and more frequently than you might expect, keep them *stateless*.

To create an event handler in Meteor/Blaze:

js:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click selector'(ev) {
    Session.set('channel', this._id);
  }
});
```

where `selector` is some DOM selector (#ID, .className, etc...).

In this example I've set the channel to the `_id` key of `this` in context of the `myTemplate` that was clicked. This would be useful if `myTemplate` was presenting a list of users for example.